# Converting daily/hourly/minute water level data to daily average values (using pandas - python)

Tags: python, resampling

I am using python for a short while and have come up against a problem.

I have some water level data which is in the form of "2015-07-23 10:45:00".
I want to resample this data as daily average values
and then export that series of dates and values.
I guess I need to get the daily average values from all this hourly or
minute data.

Anyway help or advice would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to create a time series then [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```
df = pd.read_csv("xxxx.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
df_daily = df.resample('D')
```